# Custom object has read rights, but visualforce page shows null value

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm encountering a strange problem with my APEX Class and Visualforce page that only occurs on Production and not on Acceptation or Development. 
There is a custom Object called soco__Product__c and Event_PN__c. In my apex Class I do a SOQL query for all Event_PN__c. Then I loop through the events and get the product (soco__Product__c) connected to the Event with the field  event.Product__c. Next I put the event and the product in a custom Object called objectItem which contains an Event_PN__c and a soco__Product__c object.

```
public List<objectItem> getEvents(){                        
    String today = date.today().format();
    List<Event_PN__c> events = [
        SELECT Id,Name, Event_Start_Date__c,Event_End_Date__c,Maximum_Registration__c,Webshop_Call_to_Action__c,
        Venue_City__c,Venue_Country__c,Venue_Postal_Code__c,Venue_State__c,Venue_Status__c,Venue_Street_Address_1__c,Venue_Street_Address_2__c,
        Doelgroep__c,Multidisciplinair__c,Event_Description__c,Event_Vision__c,Accreditatie_event__c, Product__c, Alleen_voor_leden__c, Event_Type__c,Link_naar_foto_event__c
        FROM Event_PN__c 
        WHERE Zichtbaarheid_in_webshop__c = 'Publiek'
        AND Status__c = 'Publiceren'
        AND Event_Start_Date__c >= today   
        ORDER BY Event_Start_Date__c ASC        
    ];
    List<objectItem> all_events = new List<objectItem>{};       

    for (Event_PN__c event : events) {
        objectItem o = new objectItem();
        o.Event = event;
        soco__Product__c prod = [SELECT Id,soco__Standard_Price__c,soco__Destination__c FROM soco__Product__c WHERE Id = :event.Product__c LIMIT 1];
        if(prod!=null) { 
            o.productcon = prod;                            
            all_events.add(o);
        }
    }       
    return all_events;  
}
```

In my APEX code I can see that the Site Guest User of the community I'm in is able to retrieve all the records from the database because I can see all the information using system.debug(); But when I try to show the product fields in my VisualForce page, the whole Product object is null. Even though the Event_PN__c object in objectItem() is shown on the page with all its fields.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!Events}" var="event" id="theRepeat">
<li class='event-item grid-item {!IF(event.Event.Multidisciplinair__c,"Multidisciplinair", SUBSTITUTE(event.Event.Doelgroep__c, ";", " "))}'>
    <div class="event-item__post {!If(event.Event.Alleen_voor_leden__c=='Ja' ,'ico-access','') }">

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!event.Event.Alleen_voor_leden__c=='Ja'}">
            <img src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Webshop, 'base/images/uploads/Pnet-logo-rood.png')}" class="pnet_logo tooltip-link"/>

        </apex:outputPanel>

        <a class="event-item__header" href="/Webshop?id={!event.Event.Id}">
            <div class="event-item__header-in">
                <h3>{!event.Event.Name}</h3>                                           
            </div>
        </a>                                    
        <div class="event-item__content">
            <ul>
                <li class="ico ico-data">
                    <c:MFSI_FormatDateTime date_Timevalue="{!event.Event.Event_Start_Date__c}" date_dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
                </li>
                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!event.Event.Doelgroep__c != ''}">
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!event.Event.Multidisciplinair__c}">
                        <li class="ico ico-person">Multidisciplinair</li>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!event.Event.Multidisciplinair__c}">
                        <li class="ico ico-person"> {!SUBSTITUTE(event.Event.Doelgroep__c, ';', ', ')}</li>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

                </apex:outputPanel>
                <li class="ico ico-place">{!event.Event.Venue_City__c}</li>
            </ul>                                        
            <p>{!event.Event.Webshop_Call_to_Action__c}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event-item__footer clearfix">
            <apex:outputLink value="/Webshop?id={!event.Event.Id}" styleClass="lees-meer" id="theLink">LEES MEER</apex:outputLink>
            <span class="price">
                <c:FormatCurrency cur_currency="{!event.productcon. soco__Standard_Price__c}" cur_showeuro="true" />
            </span>                                        
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
    </div>
</li>
</apex:repeat>
```

So whenever I try to print a value from event.productcon, the value is null.

If I am logged in as an admin in SalesForce and try to go to the specific VisualForce Page, the object is not null. So I think it's some kind of rights setting in the profiles (?). But I cannot find the solution.
Can anybody help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex runs in system mode, so you can always see all fields even if the user profile doesn't have access to them via Field Level Security.

Visualforce however, does not behave like that; if the user doesn't have explicitly FLS to the field, the field will be removed from the visualforce page. This is documented here:

[Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS)

> When rendering VisualForce pages, the platform will automatically
>   enforce CRUD and FLS when the developer references SObjects and
>   SObject fields directly in the VisualForce page. For example, if a
>   user without FLS visibility to the Phone field of the Contact object
>   was to view the below page, phone numbers would be automatically
>   removed from the table.

So you need to make sure the Guest Site profile has the correct FLS for these fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to set the FLS for a different field object, and that seems to work. But this doesn't work for the soco__Product__c object I'm working with. Anyway, this helped me a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Try creating a simple visualforce page with just that field and see if playing with the FLS does the trick. Having a simplier page would help you debug the issue.